# Executing a SQL Server Stored Procedure with parameters using PDO in php

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I seem to be having great difficulty in executing a ms sql server stored procedure that contains parameters, I am able to execute either simple select statements or stored procedures without parameters but as soon as I try to bind parameters i get the message :

`"An error occured: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 102 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [102] (severity 15) [(null)]"`

**code from php is:**

```
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    try {
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("EXEC [contractor].[sync_licence] (?)");
    $params = 5;
    $sql->bindParam(1, $params, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
    $sql->execute();
    $results = $sql->fetchAll();
    var_dump($results);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'An error occured: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

---

Can anybody help with where I am going wrong?

Comment: have you checked your prepared statement ...

Comment: how do you mean checked the prepared statement Christopher? my apologies if this is obvious but i am a little new to pdo. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For anybody interested I have found the issue with the above statement. The error message returned was basically pointing towards a syntax issue with the t-sql statement, in this case the problem was the () surrounding the ?, therefore by removing the () the procedure now works, hope this helps anybody having the same issue